# Using Task<List<Task>> for asynchronous recursive operation in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, recursion, task

Say I have two classes `A` and `B` that derive from an interface (say `IAorB`). `A` contains a list of `IAorB` objects:

```
public interface IAorB { ... }

public class A 
{
    ...
    public List<IAorB> Children { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class B { ... }
```

If I wanted apply an operation to an `IAorB` object and all its children (if any) asynchronously, would the following approach be recommended? If not, is there a better way?

```
public Task SomeOperation(IAorB object) { ... } //May take some time

public Task<List<Task>> OperateRecursively(A root)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (IAorB child in root.Children)
    {
        if (child.GetType() == typeof(B))
        {
            tasks.Add(SomeOperation(child));
        }
        else
        {
            tasks.Add(OperateRecursively(child as A));
        }
    }

    tasks.Add(SomeOperation(root));

    return tasks;
}
```

Optimally, `OperateRecursively` would return a `List` of `Tasks` that I can use `Task.WaitAll()` on. But this approach returns nested `List<Task>`s, which probably isn't optimal.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have to ask, are you even sure you have to solve the problem you have like this? It looks difficult to maintain, difficult to understand and difficult to execute.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic That's a fair question! I guess some of this comes from my fondness for functional programming where defining types recursively is very standard (lists, trees, etc.). But also, I don't know of any other way to represent it. I mean I could do away with the interface and just have type `A` and represent `B` as a kind of `A` (get rid of the distinction between terminal and non-terminal nodes) but the question about asynchronously applying a recursive operation would still apply.

Comment: With this approach, any task might end in any order, are you OK with that?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yup they're independent tasks. The only concern is that some might take longer than others so I don't want a bottleneck anywhere. Basically what I want at the end of the `OperateRecursively` is a `List` of `Task`s that I can use `Task.WaitAll()` on. But this approach returns nested `List<Task>`s which doesn't optimal.

Comment: What does `OperateRecursively` do? Because I don't see recursion here, and I see `OperateRecursivelyA` return `List<Task>` rather than `Task<List<Task>>`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The recursion is here: `tasks.Add(OperateRecursively(child));`. Also, isn't the whole idea that the `Task<TResult>` return type is used for an async method that contains a return statement in which the operand has type `TResult`? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

Comment: Do not do a `GetType()` to check to see if a thing is a `B`.  If there is a subtype of `B`, say `FancyB`, then its `GetType` will return `typeof(FancyB)` and not `typeof(B)`.  Use `is` to test whether an expression is of a particular type.  In C# 7 you can use the new `is` pattern to declare a new variable.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just got a little confused with the syntax. This should be what you are looking for:

```
// fix method signature, this doesn't run asynchronous code so it needs not be a Task
public IEnumerable<Task> OperateRecursively(A root)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (IAorB child in root.Children)
    {
        if (child is B)
        {
            tasks.Add(SomeOperation(child));
        }
        else
        {
            // 1. change to AddRange since you are adding multiple elements, not one
            // 2. fix name for actual recursion
            // 3. cast child to A since otherwise it wouldn't compile
            tasks.AddRange(OperateRecursivelyA(child as A));
        }
    }

    tasks.Add(SomeOperation(root));

    return tasks;
}
```

Which you would then simply use as

```
await Task.WhenAll(OperateRecursivelyA(someRoot));
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to do! It's just that I had a couple of `await` operations in `OperateRecursively` but I suppose I can always just `Result` to make it synchronous.

Comment: @ZacharyLim: No no no, do NOT use `Result`. That will give you deadlocks! I don't have time to answer your question today but composing sequence coroutines with async coroutines is still a little tricky. This article might help: http://davesexton.com/blog/post/async-iterators.aspx

Comment: @ZacharyLim Ah... That's why you should always post a [mcve]. If you edit your question with that I'll edit my answer, but there's a reason I used `await Task.WhenAll` rather than `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: @ZacharyLim: Note also that the solution in this answer does *not* lazily compute the sequence of tasks. It walks the entire transitive closure of the child relation. If there are a million nodes in that tree, it produces a list with a million tasks in it, rather than fetching them out one at a time on demand as you might expect an `IEnumerable<T>` to do.  If that's a requirement then again, there are ways to do that, but you need to say more clearly what your requirements are.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry about that! But the asynchronous portion of the method really is insignificant and since I shouldn't use `Result` (as pointed out by other users) I can also wrap `OperateRecursively` in an asynchronous method and pass in the results as parameters.

Comment: @EricLippert I have read multiple warnings about not using `Result` but I guess I was too shortsighted to worry about it. Would it be better if I wrap `OperateRecursively` in an asynchronous method that handles the minor `await` operations and pass in the results as parameters?